# Find oldest in the list and return the list with oldest

Tags: java, list, collections, min

Here is what I have:

```java
package victor;

import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.util.PrimitiveIterator;

public class Car {
    private String mark;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private String color;
    public Type type;

    public Car(String mark, String model, int year, String color, Type type) {
        this.mark = mark;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.color = color;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(String mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "mark='" + mark + '\'' +
                ", model='" + model + '\'' +
                ", year=" + year +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", type=" + type +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Now I have to return the oldest in my list. Here is my code:

```java
package victor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
    
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create 4 cars (mark,model, production yrs, colour, sedan/coupe/combi/cabrio)

        Car car1 = new Car("BMW", "M5", 2020, "Black", Type.SEDAN);
        Car car2 = new Car("Audi", "SQ8", 2021, "Red", Type.COUPE);
        Car car3 = new Car("Fiat", "Abarth", 2019, "Blue", Type.COUPE);
        Car carTest = new Car("Fiat", "Abarth", 2019, "Blue", Type.COUPE);
        Car car4 = new Car("Ferrari", "Pista", 2020, "Pink", Type.CABRIO);

        List<Car> carList = List.of(car1, car2, car3, car4, carTest);
        List<Car> oldCars = getOldCar(carList);
        System.out.println("This is the oldest car/s: " + oldCars);
    }

    public static List<Car> getOldCar(List<Car> carList) {
        List<Car> oldestCars = new ArrayList<>();
        Car oldCar = carList.get(0); //M5
        for (int i = 0; i < carList.size(); i++) {
            // if i put in the if statment <=  it seems i get  also the  BMW  
            if (carList.get(i).getYear() <= oldCar.getYear()) {
                oldCar = carList.get(i);
                oldestCars.add(carList.get(i));
            }
        }
        return oldestCars;
    }
}
```

I  tried to get only the 2 oldest cars but apparently I get also the first car in  as is index 0 and I cannot  figure it out how to get only the 2 Fiat cars of 2019.

Here is the output from my code:

> This is the oldest car/s: [Car{mark='BMW', model='M5', year=2020, color='Black', type=SEDAN},Car{mark='Fiat', model='Abarth', year=2019, color='Blue', type=COUPE},Car{mark='Fiat', model='Abarth', year=2019, color='Blue', type=COUPE}]

Comment: To answer your main issue...you're getting the car at the 0th index and comparing it to itself when adding to the old cars collection. You need to start at index 1. As an aside...this logic won't work in different scenarios. You should sort the collection, and take the oldest that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the existing code, when a yonger car is detected, the existing list  of old cars should be cleared/recreated to accumulate the cars related to the minimal year:

```java
public static List<Car> getOldCar1(List<Car> carList) {
    List<Car> oldestCars = new ArrayList<>();
    int minYear = 3000;
    for (Car car : carList) {
        if (car.getYear() <= minYear) {
            if (car.getYear() < minYear) {
                minYear = car.getYear();
                oldestCars.clear();
            }
            oldestCars.add(car);
        }
    }
    return oldestCars;
}
```

---

Similar solution using Stream API may group by cars by year using `Collectors.groupingBy`, and get the values by the minimal key using `Collectors.minBy`:

```java
public static List<Car> getOldCar(List<Car> carList) {
    return carList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getYear)) // Map<Integer, List<Car>>
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.minBy(Map.Entry::getKey)) // Optional<Map.Entry>
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // List<Car>
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
}
```

[Online demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/lsw)
output:

> This is the oldest car/s: [Car{mark='Fiat', model='Abarth', year=2019, color='Blue', type=COUPE}, Car{mark='Fiat', model='Abarth', year=2019, color='Blue', type=COUPE}]

Comment: i cannot compare in my situation , so   i need to  find a way  for the code i have ,

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this statement, and the reasoning of unaccepting a correct answer by Progman

Comment: answer accepted  -  sorry  but i am new in here and i was assuming that  i need to accept only if the answer its workign for my situation  not in genral  . Thanks for understanding ,

Comment: Thanks for yout  help 
your solution is also good  ;d

Comment: So you may upvote the answer if you think it's good :)

Answer (score 0):

While iterating over the list of cars there are three cases how the year of the next car is in relation to the current year of the oldest cars so far. Based on these three cases you decide if you want to add the car to the list of currently oldest cars or if you need to create a new list. The decision is like this:

1. **Year of next car > current oldest car year** - Don't do anything, the car is too young...
2. **Year of next car == current oldest car year** - Add car to oldest cars list
3. **Year of next car < current oldest car year** - Create a new list of oldest cars, starting with the current car.

The code of the `getOldCar()` method might look like this:

```
public static List<Car> getOldCar(List<Car> carList) {
    List<Car> oldestCars = new ArrayList<>();
    // always start with the first car in the list
    oldestCars.add(carList.get(0));

    // start at i=1, as the first car is already in the list
    for (int i = 1; i < carList.size(); i++) {
        Car currentCar = carList.get(i);
        int yearLimit = oldestCars.get(0).getYear();
        int currentCarYear = currentCar.getYear();
        if (currentCarYear > yearLimit) {
            // younger, not relevant
        } else if (currentCarYear == yearLimit) {
            // it fits in the current year, add it
            oldestCars.add(currentCar);
        } else {
            // it is older than every other car before, start with a new list
            oldestCars = new ArrayList<>();
            oldestCars.add(currentCar);
        }
    }
    return oldestCars;
}
```

Comment: but how i  could do it   otherwise ? -  i mean here i always add the first element to the list , there  should be  a other way ( a better way ) if i am not worng :(

Comment: @BecaliNr1 `oldestCars = new ArrayList<>();` or `oldestCars.clear();`, otherwise you keep your previously added cars in that list, even when they aren't the oldest one anymore.

Comment: i  will unnacept the ansewr since  is not  exactly what i  really need  ( please keep in mind that the answer provided by you is  working corect )

Comment: @Program   i  cannot figure it  out how to exactly do . For instance i  use the clear  but then i get only one Fiart 2019  and  next one is the Ferarri 2020 ... :( i actually get confused .

Comment: @BecaliNr1 As written in the answer, when you have a car from the **same** year as all the cars in the `oldestCars` list, you only add the car to the list. When you have a car which is **older**, then you clear the existing list or create a new list since all the previously found cars aren't the oldest anymore. You start the new list with the new oldest car. You have to use two `if()` statements to check if the year of the next car is the **same** or **older**. If the car is **younger**, you will ignore this car completely.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that @Program 

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `java 8` or above:

In your main function:

store your **carlist** in ArrayList, so that `compareTo` can be used:

then Fist sort your list and then `get(0)` for oldest and `get(size() - 1)` for newest car.

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Car car1 = new Car ("BMW", "M5", 2020, "Black");
    Car car2 = new Car ("Audi", "SQ8", 2021, "Red");
    Car car3 = new Car ("Fiat", "Abarth", 2019, "Blue");
    Car carTest = new Car ("Fiat", "Abarth", 2019, "Blue");
    Car car4 = new Car ("Ferarri", "Pista", 2020, "Pink");

      ArrayList < Car > carList = new ArrayList <> ();
      carList.add (car1);
      carList.add (car2);
      carList.add (car3);
      carList.add (car4);
      carList.add (carTest);

      Collections.sort (carList,
            (a, b)->Integer.compare (a.getYear (), b.getYear ()));

      ArrayList < Car > oldCars =
      findUsingEnhancedForLoop (carList.get (0).getYear (), carList);

      System.out.println ("This is the oldest car/s: " + oldCars.toString ());
  }

  public static ArrayList < Car > findUsingEnhancedForLoop (int year,
                                List < Car > cars)
  {

    ArrayList < Car > oldestCar = new ArrayList <> ();
    for (Car car:cars)
      {
    if (car.getYear () == year)
      {
        oldestCar.add (car);
      }
      }
    return oldestCar;
  }

}
```

Comment: yes, actually my focus was on compareTo that's why,  i am updating my answer.

Comment: I do apreciate  the answer but  i need to return  so i need to find a way  to fix  my code as it stand :d

Comment: do you want a function that return oldest car @BecaliNr1

Comment: indeed , i need something similar   i  already  have ,  but i cannot get it since i  try  to  go trough the loop twice  also  but then i  get  3 times the same car :(

Comment: unable to understand your need. @BecaliNr1

Comment: i need to  return  a list  with the oldest cars (oldest year) - so  my  list  should look like  i have   2 x  Fiat Aharth 2019  -

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer with your requirements. @BecaliNr1

Answer (score 0):

You could try an advanced for loop "for every car in car list"

```
int oldestCarsYear = 0;
Car oldestCar;
for(Car car : carList){
  if(car.getYear() <= oldestCarsYear || oldestCarsYear == 0){
    oldestCarsYear = car.getYear();
    oldestCar = car;
  }
}
oldestCars.add(oldestCar);
```

Comment: 1) there's no `getAge` method in `Car` 2) Only one (the first) oldest car is added to the list while multiple entries are possible

Comment: Yeah right , getYear was the one i was looking for.