# Find Longest mark

Tags: java

I tried to return the longest "mark" (example Ferarri and Mercede in a list) but aparently I get stuck.After I run this code I also get the(Audi) in my  output and i cannot figure it out.
Dose  anyone here can please explain me what am I doing wrong ?

This is the
--Car class--

```
    package victor;

import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.util.PrimitiveIterator;

public class Car {

    private String mark;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private String color;
    public Type type;

    public Car(String mark, String model, int year, String color, Type type) {
        this.mark = mark;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.color = color;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(String mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "mark='" + mark + '\'' +
                ", model='" + model + '\'' +
                ", year=" + year +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", type=" + type +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and here is the code i figure it  out  till  now

```
    package victor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FindLongest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car1 = new Car("BMW", "M5", 2020, "Black", Type.SEDAN);
        Car car2 = new Car("Audi", "SQ8", 2021, "Red", Type.COUPE);
        Car car3 = new Car("Fiat", "Abarth", 2019, "Blue", Type.SEDAN);
        Car carTest = new Car("Fiat", "Abarth", 2019, "Blue", Type.COUPE);
        Car car4 = new Car("Ferarri", "Pista", 2020, "Pink", Type.CABRIO);
        Car carTest1 = new Car("Mercede", "Abarth", 2019, "Blue", Type.COUPE);
        List<Car> carList = List.of(car1, car2, car3, carTest, car4, carTest1);
        List<Car> longestMark = findLongestMark(carList);
        System.out.println("This is longest mark : " + longestMark);
    }

    public static List<Car> findLongestMark(List<Car> carList) {
        List<Car> nfindLongCarMark = new ArrayList<>();
        Car longMark = carList.get(0);
        for (int c = 0; c < carList.size(); c++) {
            if (carList.get(c).getMark().length() > longMark.getMark().length()) {
                longMark = carList.get(c);
                nfindLongCarMark.add(carList.get(c));
            }
        }
        return nfindLongCarMark;
    }
    }
```

Comment: "aparently I get stuck" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Hello , I mean that i cannot figure it out how to  remove the "Audi" from output and  ofcourse  why  do i get  "Audi" also in my output .

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, and why not?

Comment: @BecaliNr1 What should be returned when you have multiple cars with the same length of "mark" and they all have the longest "mark"?

Comment: @ScottHunter  , I did not use debugger  since i  do not know  how to  :(.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn.

Comment: @Progman  ,  I  have to return the  a list zith the  longest "mark"  so in my  case    i need to return only   Ferarri and Mercede  (  i  edited my  question since i put  Mercedes  instead of Mercede )  so in  my list  i  sould have only  those 2  marks  not others :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find oldest in the list and return the list with oldest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70498491/find-oldest-in-the-list-and-return-the-list-with-oldest)

Comment: This is the same question, just for a different field.

Comment: @ScottHunter , With all due respect , I presee debug  ( i use IntelIJ ) and i do not see any info that  could  help me   ( or i  am totaly blind) - I  will  have a look on  internet to see more about it .
Thanks for  it

Comment: Never heard "mark and model" before, usually "make and model". Just interested, is "mark" really used?

Comment: @Progman I  have used that in my program before , but aparently I have to use diferent aproche (a better way )  since there  I  always add the first element . :(

Comment: A debugger allows you to step through the execution; in this case, you would have seen that when your function found a new long-mark, it left what used to be long-mark in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be clearing the results' list (`nfindLongCarMark`) each time you find a mark with longer than the current maximum length.

So (pseudocode):

```
add the first car to the results' list.
for each car in the list do:
    if the length of the car's mark is equal to the current maximum then:
        add the car to the results' list.
    otherwise if the length of the car's mark is greater than the current maximum then:
        clear the list first!
        then add the car to the results' list.
```

For example, imagine you would like to search the maximum numbers in a data set of integers like the following:

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4`

... you only care about the numbers which are equal to the global maximum (ie `5` in this case). But according to your current algorithm in your question you add to the results' list the element which is greater than the current maximum (the *current maximum* in your algorithm is the maximum of all the elements that the loop has checked up to that point).

So if you run your algorithm with the above input, you will get something like: `2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5`. And that's because when the loop tests for the second element (`2`) it will be greater than the current value of maximum (which was initialized with a `1`), so `2` will be added to the list. After that, `3` will be greater than `2` so it will too be added to the results' list, and so on.

Comment: This is what i  was looking for , i  eddited your answer and i added my code to it as proof  that it's good ( being new in here i dont know if it was a  wise option :(  )
Answer is accepted :D
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is, you can introduce a method in class to return length of string and use below stream function.

```
// Method to return length of string
public int lengthOfMark() {
            return this.mark != null ? this.mark.length() : 0;
        }

// find longest length object.
final Car car = carList.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Car::lengthOfMark))
                .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
        System.out.println("This is longest mark : " + car);
```

Hoping this will help you.

Comment: Thank you  for your response , aparently i have to use  another aproche   to be exact  i need to go zith my similar code but  as i  already  get the answer   is just to  clean the list before i add  to it .